# Why is the button disabled work if I draw two shapes and undo and not if i draw one shape and undo?

Tags: java, jpanel, action, jbutton

Basically I am making an application that allows you to draw shapes. I am working on a feature that would allow you to "undo a draw". All drawing occurs on the drawing panel. I got the algorithm part of the undo down, move to a stack...., but I can't get the undo button to disable after there are no more shapes to draw in the collection.(can't undo any more )

These are my two collections that I use to store my shapes

```
 //to store shapes that have been drawn 
 private final List<ShapeColorThickness> myShapesToDraw
  //store shapes that have been "undone"
  private final Stack<ShapeColorThickness> myUndoShapes;
```

This is the AbstractAction class used to handle clicks to the undo button.

```
public class UndoAction extends AbstractAction{
    private final DrawingPanel myDrawingPanel;
    public UndoAction(String name, DrawingPanel panel) {
        super(name);
        myDrawingPanel = panel;
        //I don't want the button to be enabled in the beginning.
        setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        myDrawingPanel.undo();
        boolean canUndo = myDrawingPanel.canUndo();
        setEnabled(myDrawingPanel.canUndo());            
    }
}
```

This is where I initialized the undo button

```
new JButton(new UndoAction("Undo", myDrawingPanel)
```

And pertinent code in DrawingPanel.java

```
public boolean canUndo() {
    //if there are no shapes left in shapes drawn, you cannot undo 
    return !myShapesToDraw.isEmpty();
}
  public void undo() {
    myUndoShapes.push(myShapesToDraw.remove(myShapesToDraw.size() - 1));
    repaint();
}
```

When I add a Shape and proceed to remove it, the undo button stays enabled. I've been trying to debug this but just cant figure it out. I put a breakpoint next to

```
boolean canUndo = myDrawingPanel.canUndo();
```

And saw that it evaluated to false when i pressed the undo button and stepped through the code. But the button still remains enabled. What's even stranger is that the undo button disables itself perfectly fine if i add 2 shapes and remove them both. Does anyone know what this issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think cause the issue was that when i constructed the button with the action, I did something like

```
JButton button = new JButton(new UndoAction(.....));
```

And later in some part of my code, I called

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```

I am not sure how the setEnabled on the button affects the action enabled state but after i made sure that all calls that affected state came from the Action class, I managed to fix my issue.